# Can anyone help me to convert Access Query to MS SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ms-access

Hi I have a access query, Can any one help me please me out to convert the query to MS SQL 2008 Query.

Struggling with `Transform` and `PIVOT`.

Access Query is:

```
TRANSFORM Count(vwg_vkCustomers.CustomerNo) AS CountOfCustomerNo
SELECT vwg_vkCustomers.ClassID, vwg_vkCustomers.SubjectTypeID, vwg_vkCustomers.TutorCode
FROM vwg_vkCustomers
WHERE (((vwg_vkCustomers.TutorCode)="123456") AND ((vwg_vkCustomers.CustomerAdded)>#6/21/2011#))
GROUP BY vwg_vkCustomers.ClassID, vwg_vkCustomers.SubjectTypeID, vwg_vkCustomers.TutorCode
PIVOT vwg_vkCustomers.Type;
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the context in which you feel you have to convert it?

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: I need to use this on SQL Server database instead of Access...

Comment: What's the front end? Access? If so, and you're correctly using ODBC linked tables, you likely don't have to change it at all -- Jet/ACE and ODBC will convert it for you to something SQL Server will interpret correctly.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: This query is written in Access but the back-end is SQL Server, I am trying to write the similar query in SQL Server but I discovered that PIVOT in SQL Server in not very good. You have to define the columns in Query, which means if you don't know the number of columns or they vary, you cant use PIVOT. in SQL Server PIVOT on only useful where you exactly know the number of columns like SUN, MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT.

Comment: If you're executing it from Access, why rewrite it? Is Access producing the wrong results with what it sends to SQL Server via ODBC? Is it slow? If none of those things is the case, why do you feel you need to convert it to T-SQL?

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: Because we want to get rid of slow Access queries. I have a window application which produces day to day reports, want to add all Access queries to that application to make it more user friendly and Quick.

Comment: A slow Access query that returns the requested data is inferior to some other query that doesn't return the right data? That is, how do you know he SQL Server solution will be faster? Have you actually run the SQL Profiler to see what Access/Jet/ACE is actually sending to the SQL Server? You might be able to tweak things to make it work better based on that examination.

Comment: Its slow because in access for each query my client has to change the parameters manually, which is pain. they want a windows application instead, where they can select parameters from dropdown controls. They really don't want to see access interface anymore.

Comment: I haven't a clue what you're alluding to here -- you can build exactly that kind of UI in Access. There is absolutely no reason the parameters have to be changed manually. It seems you don't know much at all about Access, in which case I guess it's a good thing that you're moving away from it.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: Dear David, I am just a developer, I am not the one to decide what to user or what not to use. My Client don't want to use Access anymore, thats the main reason behind it and you are right, I am not very familiar with Access, never used it professionally, only used access for a small project in collage about 10 years ago. I am more a C#, SQL Server Developer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the T-SQL version of IIF, but this is the Access-version of a crosstab query that doesn't use TRANSFORM/PIVOT. Repeat the IIF expression for each column you want:

```
SELECT vwg_vkCustomers.ClassID, vwg_vkCustomers.SubjectTypeID, vwg_vkCustomers.TutorCode,
Sum(IIF(vwg_vkCustomers.Type="Whatever",1,0) AS TypeWhatever 
FROM vwg_vkCustomers
WHERE (((vwg_vkCustomers.TutorCode)="123456") AND ((vwg_vkCustomers.CustomerAdded)>#6/21/2011#))
GROUP BY vwg_vkCustomers.ClassID, vwg_vkCustomers.SubjectTypeID, vwg_vkCustomers.TutorCode
```

Answer (score 2):

Combine this with TimD's answer, since I don't wrangle `TRANSFORM` very often....

For `Iif`, use `CASE`:

```
...
CASE vwg_vkCustomers.Type
WHEN 'Whatever' 1
ELSE 0
END,
...
```

Note that you use single quotes instead of double.

Comment: @Scorpion ,take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx